# KnockoutJS: show HTML - fill HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I need to achieve an interesting effect with KnockoutJS. Imagine that I have the simplest model:

```js
var Item = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable("");
};
```

And of course I have a ViewModel:

```js
var ItemList = function () {
var self = this;
self.list = ko.observableArray();
}
```

Then the fun begins. Right here in the ViewModel I get a few blocks of HTML markup. How many-is unknown. For each block I need to immediately show HTML-markup:

```js
var blocks = await getBlocks();
$.each(blocks, function (index, value) {
    //At this point (as planned), the blocks should be displayed 
    //together with a rotating loading animation.
    self.list.push(new Item());
});
```

Next (again in ViewModel) I need to get the data to fill these blocks:

```js
$.each(self.list(), async function (index, value) {
    var data = await getData("some-url");
    //At this point, the blocks should be filled with data, 
    //and the spinning loading animation should disappear.
    self.list().push(data.results[0].title);
});
```

And now all together:

```js
 var Item = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable("");
};

var ItemList = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.list = ko.observableArray();
    var blocks = await getBlocks();
    $.each(blocks, function (index, value) {
        self.list.push(new Item());
    });

    $.each(self.list(), async function (index, value) {
        var data = await getData("some-url");
        self.list().push(data.results[0].title);
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ItemList());
```

HTML for all this ugliness looks very simple:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: list">
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
</div>
```

This approach does not work as expected. And I do not understand how you can do this with KnockoutJS. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that assumes:

- There's one call that tells us how many items we'll eventually render
- For each of those items, there's a call that needs to complete to render the actual UI

I've made the individual items responsible for their own loading of data. This makes it easier to write the received data, that can return in any order, to the corresponding list item.

The steps you'll see the UI render:

1. The call to retrieve the data for rendering the initial list is loading: display a general loading message
2. We created a list item for every item we're retrieving. All items have started their data load, but display a loading state until they're done
3. One by one, the individual data loads complete and the list elements receive their contents.

```js
const { getProductIdsAsync, getProductAsync } = apiMethods();

function Item(id) {
  this.name = ko.observable(null);
  this.loading = ko.pureComputed(() => !this.name());
  
  getProductAsync(id).then(this.name);
};

Item.fromId = id => new Item(id);

function List() {
  this.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.loading = ko.pureComputed(() => !this.items().length);
  
  getProductIdsAsync()
    .then(ids => ids.map(Item.fromId))
    .then(this.items);
}

ko.applyBindings({ list: new List() });


// Mocking of some async API, not relevant to question:
function apiMethods() {
  const productCatalogDB = {
    1: "Apples",
    2: "Oranges",
    3: "Bananas"
  };

  const delayed = (f, minT, maxT) => 
    (...args) => 
      new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(
          () => res(f(...args)),
          minT + Math.random() * (maxT - minT)
        )
      });

  return {
    getProductIdsAsync: delayed(
      () => Object.keys(productCatalogDB), 500, 1200),
    getProductAsync: delayed(
      id => productCatalogDB[id], 500, 1500)
  };
}
```

```css
.loading {
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p data-bind="visible: list.loading">
  Loading catalog ids...
</p>

<ul data-bind="foreach: list.items">
  <li data-bind="css: { loading: loading }, text: name() || 'Loading...'">
    
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please excuse me for taking so long to answer. You gave an amazing, exhaustive answer. Thank you very much. You helped me a lot in solving my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This line of your code is obviously wrong:

```
self.list().push(data.results[0].title);
```

It should be:

```
value.title(data.results[0].title);
```

Comment: Yes, it really was a mistake. But what can you say about the solution of this problem.

Comment: I cannot help without knowing what you're expecting and how it's behaving differently. Simply saying it "does not work" isn't sufficient.

Comment: It's not that doesn't work, but the fact that I don't understand how to do it. I need to after the document is loaded seemed empty HTML-blocks. They are filled only after the data is loaded using Ajax.

Comment: I don't see anything else out of place in your code, but perhaps I don't understand what problem you're having.